# Mouse click doesn’t work after waking MacBook Pro 2018

Tags: mac, usb, mouse, sleep

I am using a MacBook Pro 2018 and I am connecting a USB mouse and USB keyboard with a USB hub.

If I enter sleep mode and and try to wake the system, the mouse click doesn’t seem to work. It just moves and scrolls and I have 6 mouses, all the same problems.

Keyboard works fine.

The solution I found is disconnect and reconnect mouse from the USB hub.

I've just did a clean install of macOS and updated the latest version, but I'm still experiencing the same problem. I tried to SMC/PRAM reset but the problem still persists.

Is there a way to solve it?